# Disable FormGroup controls in Reactives FormModule in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using `Reactive FormsModule` in `Angular2`. Now, I want to disable all controls of `FormGroup`. I can use `readOnly` property in all controls but it is not better solution as we might add new fields in near future.
So, Is there anyway to disable `FormGroup` controls in short ?

Answer (score 48):

> Now, I want to disable all controls of FormGroup

Use [**disable()**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disabled):

```
YOUR_FORM_GROUP.disable();
```

[**DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddboca)

Comment: It din't wok. I used `FORM_CONTROL.disable()`

Comment: What do you mean, man?! You're saying that my answer didn't work, however you say `disable()` (which is exactly what I used in my answer) did work?! What's the difference?! Please explain..

Comment: `YOUR_FORM_GROUP.disable();` dint work so I disabled all controls one by one.

Comment: @JeetenParmar what happens when you use it? It should work, as documented.. does it throws errors? Simply "doesn't work" isn't helpful? Also.. did you understand that `YOUR_FORM_GROUP`  should replaced by your variable (form group), right?

Comment: @JeetenParmar please, check the update in my answer. I provided a demo and It really works..

Comment: @ParagGhadge I'm 100% sure this works, you can even read the docs that I posted above. Anyway, I've updated the DEMO. Also... out of curiosity, did you downvoted it?

Comment: its not working when you use it on constructor, you have to use it oninit or after the  oninit cycle, maybe this helps. this answer is the correct one

Comment: I had problems using disable() due to this problem:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22556

Answer (score 10):

Warning: if anyone is calling disable() inside of a an observable which is watching for changes on the form, you will want to pass in the argument `{emitEvent: false}`

like

```
control.disable({emitEvent: false});
```

This helped me avoid a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` Error.